# Creating a universal controller function with Web2Py

Tags: python, model-view-controller, web2py

I have a function I want to call on every single page load, regardless of controller. At first I thought I would just stick it in a model and have it be called whenever the module loads. But the function is dependent on other models, some of which may not be loaded yet.

So then I thought if it's possible to control model load order, I could put it in a late-loaded module, but I don't know if controlling model order is possible, and I'm pretty sure one model referencing another violates MVC. (Yes? No?)

What I really want is some sort of universal pre-controller function, called before the regular controllers but after all the models have loaded. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model files are executed in alphabetical order, so you can put the function call at the end of the last model file. See [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/4#Workflow) for more details.

Comment: Anthony- great thanks. So if I made a model file called "zz", I could have it essentially act as a pre-controller for my app? Would it have access to all the same things normal controllers would?

Comment: Yes, it will have access to everything defined in the preceding model files as well as the usual web2py API objects.